# How to create Kubernetes users limited to namespaces

Tags: namespaces, kubernetes

I have a hard time trying to set up my (test) Kubernetes cluster so that it have a few users and a few namespaces, and a user can only see specific namespaces. Is there a way to do that? If yes, what is needed to

1. Create a user
2. Limit a user to a specific namespace or namespaces
3. Use Kubernetes (via kubectl) as a specific user

Answer (score 5):

You could setup ABAC (http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/) and limit users to namespaces:

In the policy file you would have something like this if your user was `bob` and you wanted to limit him to the namespace `projectCaribou`:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1",
  "kind": "Policy",
  "spec": {
    "namespace": "projectCaribou",
    "readonly": true,
    "resource": "pods",
    "user": "bob"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, how can I actually create the users("bob") on k8.

Comment: this solution might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42186135/9508556 @SuhasChikkanna