# How to Add Users to Kubernetes (kubectl)?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I've created a Kubernetes cluster on AWS with [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) and can successfully administer it via `kubectl` from my local machine.

I can view the current config with `kubectl config view` as well as directly access the stored state at `~/.kube/config`, such as:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://api.{CLUSTER_NAME}
  name: {CLUSTER_NAME}
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: {CLUSTER_NAME}
    user: {CLUSTER_NAME}
  name: {CLUSTER_NAME}
current-context: {CLUSTER_NAME}
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: {CLUSTER_NAME}
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
    password: REDACTED
    username: admin
- name: {CLUSTER_NAME}-basic-auth
  user:
    password: REDACTED
    username: admin
```

I need to enable other users to also administer. This [user guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/sharing-clusters/) describes how to define these on another users machine, but doesn't describe how to actually create the user's credentials within the cluster itself. How do you do this?

Also, is it safe to just share the `cluster.certificate-authority-data`?

Comment: Looks like you want [service accounts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/service-accounts/)

Comment: I've read the docs on service accounts, which show that they are easy to create and retrieve their `ca.crt` and `token`, but this isn't enough or correct for setting up kubeconfig. If you know how to configure kubeconfig, please do tell.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

For a full overview on Authentication, refer to the official Kubernetes docs on [Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens) and [Authorization](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/)

For users, ideally you use an Identity provider for Kubernetes (OpenID Connect).

If you are on GKE / ACS you integrate with respective Identity and Access Management frameworks

If you self-host kubernetes (which is the case when you use kops), you may use [coreos/dex](https://github.com/coreos/dex#kubernetes--dex) to integrate with LDAP / OAuth2 identity providers - a good reference is this detailed 2 part [SSO for Kubernetes](https://thenewstack.io/single-sign-kubernetes-command-line-experience/) article.

kops (1.10+) now has built-in [authentication support](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/release-1.11/docs/authentication.md) which eases the integration with AWS IAM as identity provider if you're on AWS.

for Dex there are a few open source cli clients as follows:

- [Nordstrom/kubelogin](https://github.com/Nordstrom/kubelogin)
- [pusher/k8s-auth-example](https://github.com/pusher/k8s-auth-example)

If you are looking for a quick and easy (not most secure and easy to manage in the long run) way to get started, you may abuse `serviceaccounts` - with 2 options for specialised Policies to control access. (see below)

**NOTE since 1.6  Role Based Access Control is strongly recommended! this answer does not cover RBAC setup**

**EDIT**: Great, but outdated (2017-2018), guide by Bitnami on [User setup with RBAC](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/) is also available.

Steps to enable service account access are (depending on if your cluster configuration includes RBAC or ABAC policies, these accounts may have full Admin rights!):

**EDIT**: [Here is a bash script to automate Service Account creation - see below steps](https://gist.github.com/so0k/8fad3b1639b3d70cd841703fda67f16b)

1. Create service account for user `Alice`

   ```
   kubectl create sa alice
   ```
2. Get related secret

   ```
   secret=$(kubectl get sa alice -o json | jq -r .secrets[].name)
   ```
3. Get `ca.crt` from secret (using OSX `base64` with `-D` flag for decode)

   ```
   kubectl get secret $secret -o json | jq -r '.data["ca.crt"]' | base64 -D > ca.crt
   ```
4. Get service account token from secret

   ```
   user_token=$(kubectl get secret $secret -o json | jq -r '.data["token"]' | base64 -D)
   ```
5. Get information from your kubectl config (current-context, server..)

   ```
   # get current context
   c=$(kubectl config current-context)

   # get cluster name of context
   name=$(kubectl config get-contexts $c | awk '{print $3}' | tail -n 1)

   # get endpoint of current context 
   endpoint=$(kubectl config view -o jsonpath="{.clusters[?(@.name == \"$name\")].cluster.server}")
   ```
6. On a fresh machine, follow these steps (given the `ca.cert` and `$endpoint` information retrieved above:

   1. Install `kubectl`

      ```
       brew install kubectl
      ```
   2. Set cluster (run in directory where `ca.crt` is stored)

      ```
       kubectl config set-cluster cluster-staging \
         --embed-certs=true \
         --server=$endpoint \
         --certificate-authority=./ca.crt
      ```
   3. Set user credentials

      ```
       kubectl config set-credentials alice-staging --token=$user_token
      ```
   4. Define the combination of alice user with the staging cluster

      ```
       kubectl config set-context alice-staging \
         --cluster=cluster-staging \
         --user=alice-staging \
         --namespace=alice
      ```
   5. Switch current-context to `alice-staging` for the user

      ```
       kubectl config use-context alice-staging
      ```

To control user access with policies (using [ABAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/abac/)), you need to create a [`policy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens) file (for example):

```
{
  "apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1",
  "kind": "Policy",
  "spec": {
    "user": "system:serviceaccount:default:alice",
    "namespace": "default",
    "resource": "*",
    "readonly": true
  }
}
```

Provision this `policy.json` on every master node and add `--authorization-mode=ABAC --authorization-policy-file=/path/to/policy.json` flags to API servers

This would allow Alice (through her service account) read only rights to all resources in default namespace only.

Comment: Although, it would be better to provide read-only access using ChatOps, log shipping and manage deployments through CI systems. The only annoying part is, how to enable easy console access to Developers ...

Comment: for dashboard access use `kubectl proxy &` and point to locahost:8001 api/v1/proxy - kubernetes-dashboard service in kube-system namespace

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was looking for. One clarification, though: step 3 creates a ca.crt file, but step 6.2 is looking for a ca.pem file. Is some translation required, or was this just a typo?

Comment: also note that you could use export KUBECONFIG=alice-config on your machine to generate a single alice-config file (with certs embedded) and just send that to alice (telling her to copy it to ~/kube/config) - but this would complicate her tasks if she needs to manage multiple clusters and contexts

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks. Maybe you'd even consider writing something up for Kubernetes.io.

Comment: correct, on OSX man `base64` shows `-D` for decode (uppercase d)

Comment: @VincentDeSmet you say "better support for user objects is still in the pipeline", do you know if anything has changed since then? Maybe there's an RFC or open PRs/issues in kubernetes/kubernetes?

Comment: @gmile - User Identity will never be a part of Kubernetes and instead will be managed through IdentityProviders. k8s supports oidc, and with something like CoreOS/dex you can hook it up to LDAP / OAuth2 providers. (which is what we did https://github.com/honestbee/dex-app)

Comment: Why a service account? I thought service accounts were for defining pod access, and that for users you would use user accounts?

Comment: Hi @DavidHam - please read the full answer - you'd need identity provider for users. service accounts basically provide a JWT for API access and can be used for robots / programs and shouldn't be used for users as highlighted in detail in the answer

Comment: I have to run `secret=$(kubectl get sa alice -o json | jq -r '.secrets[].name')` on my computer to get the secret.

Comment: secret=$(kubectl get sa alice -o json | jq -r '.secrets[].name')
this is not working, it show error message: 
"jq: error (at <stdin>:11): Cannot iterate over null (null)"

Answer (score 4):

You say :

> I need to enable other users to also administer.

But according to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#users-in-kubernetes)

> Normal users are assumed to be managed by an outside, independent service. An admin distributing private keys, a user store like Keystone or Google Accounts, even a file with a list of usernames and passwords. In this regard, Kubernetes does not have objects which represent normal user accounts. Regular users cannot be added to a cluster through an API call.

You have to use a third party tool for this.

== Edit ==

One solution could be to manually create a user entry in the [kubeconfig file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubeconfig-file/). From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/sharing-clusters/) :

```
# create kubeconfig entry
$ kubectl config set-cluster $CLUSTER_NICK \
    --server=https://1.1.1.1 \
    --certificate-authority=/path/to/apiserver/ca_file \
    --embed-certs=true \
    # Or if tls not needed, replace --certificate-authority and --embed-certs with
    --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true \
    --kubeconfig=/path/to/standalone/.kube/config

# create user entry
$ kubectl config set-credentials $USER_NICK \
    # bearer token credentials, generated on kube master
    --token=$token \
    # use either username|password or token, not both
    --username=$username \
    --password=$password \
    --client-certificate=/path/to/crt_file \
    --client-key=/path/to/key_file \
    --embed-certs=true \
    --kubeconfig=/path/to/standalone/.kube/config

# create context entry
$ kubectl config set-context $CONTEXT_NAME \
    --cluster=$CLUSTER_NICK \
    --user=$USER_NICK \
    --kubeconfig=/path/to/standalone/.kube/config
```

Comment: I read that in the docs as well, but the thing is I created my cluster with Kops and it created the initial admin user, so there must be a way to create another one.

Comment: Yes, once the user is created in the cluster, you'd use the `kubectl config` command with `set-cluster`,`set-credentials` and `set-context` instructions as I mentioned in the original question. But how do you create the actual user in the cluster? Where do you get the actual certs supplied along with those instructions?

Comment: Hi @peterl, I'm having the same doubts... did you you ever solve that?

Comment: Yes, I used the solution from Vincent De Smet, which worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

bitnami guide works for me, even if you use minikube. Most important is you cluster supports RBAC.
https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/

Comment: Don't you mean RBAC? Can you clarify a bit, this is borderline link-only.