# Add admin user for Jenkins to kubeadm kubernetes cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, authorization

I created a Kubernetes cluster for a single-master multi-node cluster using kubeadm following the official kubernetes guide:

[Kubernetes cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

I currently connect my laptop to the cluster via this command:

```
kubectl get nodes --username kubernetes-admin --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
```

However, I now want to add a separate user (or same actual user but different name) for our Jenkins to run commands. I just want a separate username for access/logging purposes.

How can I easily add another "jenkins" username (possibly with its own cert) in the config file? Kubeadm automatically uses `--authorization-mode=Node` (or at least mine did)

Background info: Only people who may make any changes on our cluster currently have/need access, so I don't need to only give users access to certain namespaces etc. Also, keep in mind we will have a cluster per environment: dev, UAT, production, etc.

Comment: you can deploy jenkins using another `namespace` kindly follow this link : https://itnext.io/deploy-jenkins-with-dynamic-slaves-in-minikube-8aef5404e9c1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's suitable to use Kubernetes `serviceAccount` and instruct your Jenkins deployment to use that account (with a bound Role):

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: jenkins
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: jenkins
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins


apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: jenkins
  name: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:     
      serviceAccountName: jenkins
```

Comment: Ok, so 2 things. The Jenkins we use is currently not a pod, it's a VM outside the kubernetes cluster. And how do I go about adding this Service Account if this caters for a non-pod Jenkins.

Comment: This also cleared up some things for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022748/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-token-for-a-normal-user-in-kubernetes