# Granting a non-root user the access of kubectl in kubernetes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, sudo, kubectl

I can access the `kubectl` with root user. I want to restrict the access of `kubectl` to non-root users so that they can perform all the `kubectl` operations.
How should I achieve the same?

Comment: The question should be - **enable** the access of cluster to a non-root users using `kubectl`.

Answer (score -1):

`kubectl` client it's distributed as a binary file so depending on your host you might give exec access to all users by doing `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl`

or you can add a custom rule to your `/etc/sudoers` by using `visudo`

```
your_user ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

your user will be able to run `kubectl` like this

```
sudo kubectl ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Hernan Garcia.I needed to give a non-root user access of kubectl. Created .kube directory under non-root linux user and copied /etc/kubernetes/config file to .kube file owned by non-root user.It worked for me.

Comment: I can confirm that copying the file `/root/.kube/config` and the certificates as configured in `/root/.kube/config` from  `/root/.minikube/` into the User Directory `/home/<user_login>/.minikube` enables the access to the _Kubernetes_ cluster. In `/root/.minikube/` you will also find the CA key `/root/.minikube/ca.key` which will enable you to create custom user certificates. In the case to disable the access you would just remove those certificates from the User Directory.

Comment: The access to the _Kubernetes_ Cluster with `kubectl` without the certificates should fail: `$ kubectl get pods` ->
`The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

Comment: As **Warning** I must say that this procedure gives **root** access to the _Kubernetes_ Cluster. Thus the better procedure would be to go through the correct User Authorisation Procedure as explained at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42186135/7774231

Comment: @MrunalTheCoder is there a better way? I mean to re-generate cluster config for non-root user?